# what is the difference between calling function with () and without(). When we assign functions to variables?

Tags: jquery

I want to know what is the difference , when we call function with round Brackets() and without brackets (). Suppose if i have a function like

```
function($) {

    var hideAnswers = function() {

        $('#faqGrid tr td').each(function(){

            var $td = $(this);
            $td.children('div .answer').hide();

        }); //end of $('#faqGrid tr td').each(fn)

    }; //end of var hideAnswers = function() {}

    var showMessage = function(message){

        alert(message);

    }; //end of var showMessage = function(){}

    hideAnswers();  //working
    hideAnswers;    // not working

}(jQuery); // end of  function($) {
```

The second one **hideAnswers;** is now working in this case. Also i want to ask when we assign function to variable and when we don't?

Also suppose if i have a button, on click of which i want to call this function then how can we call it Like

```
<input type="button" onclick = hideAnswers(); />  // is it right?
```

And what if i also want to pass value to this function on my xhtml page. Like

```
<input type="button" onclick = showMessage("what is your name "); />  // is it right?
```

Thanks

Comment: Try and ask one question at a time. SO isn't for laundry lists =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The () causes the function to execute the code inside it's definition. Without the (), you are simply referring to the function itself--which is quite useful. You can store functions in variables and pass them around.

This might help illustrate:

```
function someFunc(){
    alert("hello from someFunc");
}

function someOtherFunc(executeMe){
    executeMe();
}

someOtherFunc(someFunc);
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you are not calling the function if you don't use `()`.

Just writing the name of the function (like `hideAnswers`) does nothing. It's used to pass the function as a parameter to another function or assigning it to a variable for example. It does not call it.